# Changing UIScrollVIew Content Inset triggers scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I use the following code to set the `contentInset` for my `tableView`.

```
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(109, 0, 44, 0);
```

But this triggers the `UIScrollView` delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, is there any workaround to avoid this situation?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can try removing the scroll views delegate before setting the content insets. Then reapply the delegate.

```
id scrollDelegate = scrollView.delegate;
scrollView.delegate = nil;
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(109, 0, 44, 0);
scrollView.delegate = scrollDelegate;
```

Comment: Hi. The question is about `contentInset`, not `contentOffset`. and yes, I did try this method. but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable to check if you want to act when **scrollViewDidScroll** is triggered. And in **scrollViewDidScroll** check for this variable and apply your actions accordingly. Its the only solution worked for me. Set this variable true or false before you want to skip.